# Express - Grab a value from response object when request ends unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request, response

I have a node-express app and would like to figure if it is possible to grab the response object body when a request ends unexpectedly, i have a listener like below,

```
req.on("close", function() {
     // request closed unexpectedly
     console.log(res); // logs the entire response object
     console.log(res.body) // obviously logs undefined  
  })
```

I need to grab an ID from the response object when the request closes unexpectedly and then need to perform an action using that ID.

In this scenario is it possible for me to grab the ID from the response object. The response i see in the browser is a JSON and it is a streaming response (text/event-stream).

Scenario:

Consider i make 4 requests in 4 tabs of chrome and the response starts streaming, now i'm going to simply close tab 2 and tab 3 and eventually the req.on("close") would fire 2 times (one for tab 2 and the other for tab 3). I store the ID's when a request is made and in this case i have 4 ID's so now inside req.on("close") how can i map which out of 4 ID's i stored is closed

Comment: How does a request end "unexpectedly", shouldn't it just end when the user decides to leave?

Comment: @adeneo In this scenario i'm dealing with streaming data, say when a user makes a request and then the response would start streaming (text/event-stream) and if the user closes the browser or if the internet connection is interrupted or if the browser restarts then those would be considered as unexpected close.

Comment: And why then wouldn't you just get whatever you need while the user is still there, on every request, and then only use it if such an event took place, otherwise just discard it ?

Comment: Exactly, i grab and store the ID when each request is made, only thing is how do i know which request closed unexpectedly so i can use the corresponding ID to perform the operation.

Comment: And that's why I asked what "unexpectedly" was, I was wondering how you would tell something like that, and you seemed to have an answer a few comments ago ?

Comment: Again, consider i make 4 requests in 4 tabs of chrome and the response starts streaming, now i'm going to simply close tab 2 and tab 3 and eventually the req.on("close") would fire 2 times (one for tab 2 and the other for tab 3). As i already mentioned i store the ID's when a request is made and in this case i have 4 ID's so now inside req.on("close") how can i map which out of 4 ID's i stored is closed... not sure how better i can explain more than this!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122940/discussion-between-sai-and-adeneo).